# Existence of limit for every adherence point in a bounded set $U$ implies $f(U)$ is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $U \subseteq R^{n}$ be a bounded set, $f:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and 
suppose that for every  $x_0 \in \overline U$, $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0}f(x)}$ exist.
Prove  $f(U)$ is bounded.

By the hypothesis, if $x_0 \in \overline U$ , then for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $\left \| x-x_0 \right \|<\delta$ then $\left | f(x)-L \right |<\epsilon$. I don't really see how I can obtain a constant $M>0$ such that $\left | w-z \right |<M$ for every $w,z \in f(U)$. If $f$ was uniformly continuous I can see why $f(U)$ would be bounded but with the limit hypothesis only I'm stuck. Any guideline is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $f(U)$ is not bounded. Then there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ in $U$ such that $f(x_n)$ diverges to infinity ($+\infty$ or $-\infty$).

Now $U$ is bounded, so there exists a subsequence $(x_{\varphi(n)})$ of  $(x_n)$  converging to a point $y \in \overline{U}$. By hypothesis, $\lim_{x \rightarrow y} f(x)$ exists, so $\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} f(x_{\varphi(n)})$ exists. It is impossible because by construction, $f(x_{\varphi(n)})$ has to diverge to infinity.

Comment: By contradiction seems the hypothesis works very well. Thanks.